# Background in lettuce, django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, bdd, lettuce

How can i write backgrounds in lettuce tests(django), the background is run before each of scenarios,
in cucumber i can write backgrounds like that:

```
Feature: Multiple site support
  As a Mephisto site owner
  I want to host blogs for different people
  In order to make gigantic piles of money

  Background:
    Given a global administrator named "Greg"
    And a blog named "Greg's anti-tax rants"
    And a customer named "Dr. Bill"
    And a blog named "Expensive Therapy" owned by "Dr. Bill"

  Scenario: Dr. Bill posts to his own blog
    Given I am logged in as Dr. Bill
    When I try to post to "Expensive Therapy"
    Then I should see "Your article was published."

  Scenario: Dr. Bill tries to post to somebody else's blog, and fails
    Given I am logged in as Dr. Bill
    When I try to post to "Greg's anti-tax rants"
    Then I should see "Hey! That's not your blog!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Background` in *lettuce*, For example (taken from [here](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce/blob/2c982d9b285c8df229dee45991e96b2fd13882dd/tests/functional/bg_features/simple/simple.feature)):

```
Feature: Simple and successful
  As the Lettuce maintainer
  In order to make sure the output is pretty
  I want to automate its test

  Background:
    Given the variable "X" holds 2

  Scenario: multiplication changing the value
    Given the variable "X" is equal to 2
```

Comment: @falsetru - The screencast no longer exists.

Comment: @Tony, Thank you for reporting. You can find it here: https://asciinema.org/a/5219